# Como gerar nomes randômicos para imagems que vão ser upadas?

Tags: php, laravel

Galera estou tendo problema para criar nomes randômicos para minhas imagens.
   Estava tendo usando a função md5(mt_rand(1,10000) mas não obtive sucesso  utilizando em conjunto com has::file.

```
    public function anexar () {
        if(Input::hasFile('file')){
          $file = Input::file('file');
          $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
          return 'Anexado com sucesso';
          }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função uniqueid() do PHP. Ela gera um id único levando em consideração o tempo, em microssegundos. Você pode passar um prefixo para a função que ela concatenará com o id gerado.

Para mais informações: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Márcio Lordelo, sou iniciante n programação não consegui entender muito bem o uniqueid ! Tem como vc mandar um exemplo baseado no meu problema acima ?

Comment: Oi @Márcio, consegui resolver o problema aqui usando o uniqueid ! Valeu pela dica brother.

Comment: opa, não tinha visto antes você pedindo um exemplo, desculpe, fiquei alguns dias sem acessar. Que bom que conseguiu =)